# Play Sound On Button Click In a Fragment (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, button, fragment, playback

I'm new to Kotlin. I want to add "play sound on button click" event. The code works in an activity but not in a fragment.

```
btnamb.setOnClickListener{

            var  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext,R.raw.ambulance)
            mediaPlayer.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the above code like this :

```
btnamb.setOnClickListener{
    var mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.ambulance)
    mediaPlayer.start()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mediaplayer in fragment needs context. So you can use `activity.applicationContext` or `context` to get activity.